# Gmail Composing Window in Ubuntu

Tags: gmail

New to Ubuntu and am using Gmail account with it to send my emails.  Question is this:

As I'm writing my email, I notice that there appears to be a limitation of the content area available.  As I write my email, I noticed that when I hit a point, the window begins to take portions of my signature block and pop it into the email composition area.  The only way I can avoid this from happening is to add additional lines by hitting the return/enter key thus giving me more space to write in.

Can anyone out there help me alleviate this glitch as I do write some hefty email messages to my clients.  How do I reformat the composition window to give me enough space to finish my email message without popping my signature block up into the email message when I apparently hit the limitation of the present open window.

Comment: While not off-topic here, your question might do better at [linux.se].

Comment: An screenshot of the compose window when the error is happening would be useful, also please tell which OS version and which browser/version are you using ?

Comment: If you still having the problem, try the troubleshooting recommendations given at [Web App <X> isn't working correctly. How can I fix it?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79171/web-app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it).